# What does "Chap" when it describes a person?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Hello I am a student and I was wondering what "chap" means in this particular form.

> Because you ‘re not the kind of father     a chap could go when he is in trouble

These words are from the play "An inspector calls", and I couldn't understand its meaning.

After seeing Merriam Webster Dictionary, it states that *chap* as a noun have multiple meanings and they are

> the fleshy covering of a jaw
>
> the forepart of the face —usually used in plural

Source : [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chap)

And when I saw the online Dictionary dictionary.com it states that chap mean

> a fellow; man or boy.
>
> a baby or young child

Source : [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chap?s=t)

I got stuck not knowing what *chap* means in this line. does it mean a *miserable guy* or it means a *a young boy* or what ?

Its my first question for me here so please inform me if this is the right place to ask such a question or no.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked up _chap_ in the dictionary? It's one of the many colloquial words for a man, such as _fellow_ or _bloke_. It's British, rather old-fashioned and has largely been replaced by the American _guy_.

Comment: Hello, Shams. Please look at the Help Center for site requirements; this question is off-topic here as it lacks any research (eg dictionary definitions) and is probably more ELL-level. However, 'chap' here is informal, just a less highbrow/remote replacement for 'person', and (from the context, which hints at say a Bertie-Wooster-like association) having a (dated) British upper-class connection.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks so much for your help, but what shall I do to make it not off topic ?

Comment: You are supposed to look up the word in a dictionary first. If there is something about the definition that still puzzles you, ask a question explaining what you are puzzled about.

Comment: @KateBunting I appreciate your help, but what shall i do in this question ... I got my answer from the comments, shall I delete the question or flag it or do what ??

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've just knew that there is English language learners, and made an account how can I "migrate" the question to it?

Comment: @KateBunting "Old fashioned"? We were called "chaps" when we were at school. It can't be that old fashioned as it is current irony to refer to females as "chapesses". The origin "chapman", meaning a trader who buys and sells, definitely has gone out of use. It was the sort of word which one of my Japanese colleagues used, to prove he spoke proper English and not American.

Comment: @WS2 Well, _An Inspector Calls_ is set in 1912, and Edwin too calls the word 'dated'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Okay thanks alot but  can't anyone post an answer to my question to accept it ? So that this question is not in the unanswered part of the site ?

Comment: I hope not. It doesn't belong here (partly as you don't seem to want to be bothered adding linked references).

Comment: @WS2 Dated. Especially in certain expressions.  [GoogleNgramsthe sort of chap](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sort+of+chap&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). I'd even say 'chapesses' is passé now. By the way, 'proper' and 'variant' are not seen as near-antonyms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was quoting my former Japanese colleague from 1973/4, who had been a captain in the Japanese army in China during WW2. He had nothing good to say about Americans (well they did drop two atomic bombs, I suppose), but proudly told every British ex-patriate who came to the company, that he had never fired a shot in anger against our country, for which, he had undying respect.

Comment: @WS2 It's been said that CGEL is quite dated now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have edited the question as much as I can, and I am so sorry if I have done some troubles here on the site it's the first question for me here, and Thank you and anybody here for helping me.

Comment: @KateBunting, while it is quite "dated" in the sense that its etymology supports your hypothesis; ["Colloquial familiar sense of "lad, fellow, man or boy" is first attested 1716, usually with a qualifying adjective"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chap). ...I read the play in school too, it's quite famous, but it's not strange for me to hear it be retained in some dialects or colloquial/slang speaking: even men in their 20s today, I have heard them say this and I'm from the North: "*Be a good chap and get me a drink, will 'ya?*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only dictionary that adds a caveat about this sense being rather old-fashioned is Wiktionary:

> **chap** (plural chaps) (dated outside Britain and Australia)
>
> A man, a fellow.
>   *Who’s that chap over there?*

But I'd have to add that the example given,

> "Because you're not the kind of father a chap could go [to] when he is in
>   trouble"

itself conjures up an old-fashioned, upper-class impression, even in the UK. It's the sort of thing you expect a croney of Bertie Wooster's to say, not the average man in the street. So this is a higher-social-register usage of 'chap'. '*Can't A Chap Go For A Run In Peace?*' [[Boris Johnson, Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/watch-boris-dodge-reporters-on-morning-run-cant-a-chap-go-for-a-run-in-peace_uk_57f3e454e4b05636558543db?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvLnVrLw&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAIjPeGYFEJPLidf0uPqQBKsAynPJ7b6_VdxDcKmUjarxN3T1XR1h0PxqhwivFAiv8J1vLxmKtH41spz9esMp0nZxDt43IqbXUUM4e2zpzD7gi0F2VwZy6SwjsMYCLf0-11ajFN6OUltTpbb6RMwCfA-X2yK6_dAHuo1Ifouf2k82)]

Contrast say

> "There were a couple of chaps in the car park who looked a bit
>   suspicious"

which is readily identifiable as everyday speech in the UK, pretty much devoid of social register. In such examples, 'chap' is informal, just a less highbrow/remote/clinical replacement for 'person'. Often interchangeable with 'man'.

Comment: Of course, and it would be very useful to point out chap in AmE would be guy.

Comment: The play it comes from fits the first case exactly. 100 years old and set in the upper middle class.

Comment: @Lambie As I did in my original comment. _Guy_ is increasingly used in the UK too. Admittedly it's _old chap_ as a form of address that Oxford calls 'dated', rather than _chap_ in general.

Comment: @Lambie If you detail the points of similarity, I'll add that. I'm guessing that 'guy' is 'readily identifiable as everyday speech in the US, pretty much devoid of social register'. No hint of the dated UC usage. It's _very_ informal in the UK, and either slang-ish ("Those guys are bad news") or used with a pragmatic thrust to invoke cameraderie ("Can you guys please lend a hand?").